# Get rid of visual bugs for intellij idea under unity

Tags: unity, intellij

Ubuntu 13.04 i686, Unity

I just cant get rid of this buggy bottom bar, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me (Ubuntu 13.04 64bit) an update to Intellij IDEA 12.1.4 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a permanent solution using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04; there is a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107254) report that claims the problem is fixed, but it is still there for me. It may depend on what version of Java you are running.

But I can clear the problem until I next open my project by un-maximising the window (the 3rd button top left in the title bar) and then maximising the window again.